# How to make identity transformation in enlive?

Tags: clojure, enlive

I need to replace content of an element based on some condition. If condition is not met the element should be untouched.

```
(enlive/deftemplate template (io/resource "templ.html")
  []
  [:#el_id] (if (condition)
              (enlive/content ...)
              ;; otherwise identity transformation here
              ))
```

I tried to use `nil` as identity transformation, but it just removes the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`identity` function does the job. Sorry for messing you around.